# The eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix. Why "any $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$ are pairwise orthogonal" is wrong?

I have tried my best to find a counterexample, but I can.

Comment: Have you considered the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix?

Comment: It's not wrong if the matrix has determinant $\ne 0$.

Comment: Take the $2\times 2$-identity matrix and choose any basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.. only, if the eigenvectors have different eigenvalues. In general, subspaces spanned by a set of eigenvectors with equal eigenvectors have to be orthogonalized in a separate step, either by Gram-Schmidt or more often in practice, by diagonalization of another normal matrix, commuting with the original one, but not a multiple of the original in the subspaces.